# What is easiest way to send structured data via tcp using java?

Tags: java, tcp, network-programming

I have to connect to a existing C system, and the tcp packet looks like

```
typedef struct exampleDataPacket{
  int messageType;
  float dataValue;
  char  dataDesc[100];
}
```

So to send this kind of data using java, I can't find anything in my books.  What would be the best way to send/receive this kind of data?

Thanks,
CP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [DataOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/io/DataOutputStream.html) if the data you're trying to write is compatible with how it's going to be read on the C side. Check the documentation on writeFloat and writeChar carefully to see if that will actually work.

Otherwise you'll have to use a raw `OutputStream` and encode the data into bytes yourself.

Edit: Just wanted to add - my best guess is that for your purposes, `writeFloat` will work but `writeChars` will not, due to encoding issues. Instead, you'll have to use the `getBytes` method on your Java `String` to get a byte array in whatever single-byte character encoding your C code is expecting, then write those bytes to the `DataOutputStream`.

Comment: I would emphasize "Check the documentation ... carefully". When moving primitives across the wire, you're very likely to run into problems with encodings and different byte ordering.

Comment: Not only that, but everything in Java is signed while many C/C++ variables tend to be unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Java is going to have things in network byte order; it is likely the C programmer was lazy and is not expecting that (at least in my experience) and you may have to compensate for their mistake and do some byte swapping.